# How to get a list of the least used (read) files on a Linux system

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

I'm doing a clean up of a hard drive to free up some space and avoid unnecessary files, I want to get a list of the files by their frequency of usage (i.e get a list of the most files read and the least files read) so I can take a look at the files that I rarely open (read) and delete them.

I think there was a similar feature in Windows XP last time I used it but I'm not so sure, so I was wondering if there is a similar feature in Linux?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168457/how-to-list-down-all-useless-or-less-used-files-or-application-in-my-linux-serve

Comment: @Moab This can be used to get a list of files sorted by the last time they were accessed, this is not what I'm asking for, what i need is "how many times the file was accessed"

Answer (score 0):

In order to see the last access or modify time of a file in Linux, you need to use the `stat` command.  For example:

```
stat file.txt
```

or

```
stat /etc
```

Here is an excellent [article](https://www.maketecheasier.com/find-out-when-file-was-accessed-linux/) detailing it's usage.

On a side note, Windows does have this feature, as you remembered.  However, auditing has to be enabled to track these stats.

Comment: This can be used to get a list of files sorted by the last time they were accessed, this is not what I'm asking for, what i need is "how many times the file was accessed"